# Adding Roles to existing project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

im confused about adding roles to existing project which i set the Authentication to "No Authentication".
i have database in mssql with field only "username" and "password". And i use it for authentication. My question is how i adding roles like "administrator" or "userA" or "guest" for Authorization. Im so new to Mvc. Thanks!

this is my controller code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace _3131.Controllers {
    public class HomeController : Controller {

       [Authorize]
        public ActionResult Index(string button) {
            ViewData["username"] = User.Identity.Name;
            var viewdata = Convert.ToString(ViewData["username"]);

            if(viewdata == "admin") {
                return View();
            }else if(viewdata == "userA") {
                return View();
            } else if(viewdata == "userB") {
                return View();
            } else {
                return View();
            }
        }

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult About() {
            ViewData["username"] = User.Identity.Name;
            var viewdata = Convert.ToString(ViewData["username"]);

            if(viewdata == "admin") {
                return View();
            }else {
                return View("Error");
            }            
        }

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult UserA() {
            ViewData["username"] = User.Identity.Name;
            var viewdata = Convert.ToString(ViewData["username"]);

            if(viewdata == "userA" || viewdata == "admin") {
                return View();
            }else {
                return View("Error");
            }
        }

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult UserB() {
            ViewData["username"] = User.Identity.Name;
            var viewdata = Convert.ToString(ViewData["username"]);

            if (viewdata == "userB" || viewdata == "admin") {
                return View();
            } else {
                return View("Error");
            }
        }

        [Authorize]
        public ActionResult UserC() {
            ViewData["username"] = User.Identity.Name;
            var viewdata = Convert.ToString(ViewData["username"]);

            if (viewdata == "userC" || viewdata == "admin") {
                return View();
            } else {
                return View("Error");
            }
        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

1. 1.You can create a Generic Principal, that accepts two parameters identity and roles, The Authorize attribute looks at the principal
   attached to HttpContext to authorize the request.
   [https://www.sharpencode.com/article/MVC/filters-in-asp-net-mvc/authorize](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607392/Custom-Role-Providers)

```
2. You can create a Custom Role provider, which is the easiest.
```

[Role Provider in MVC](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607392/Custom-Role-Providers)

```
3. You can override Authorize Attribute
```